# custom Tool Bar dont appear when i build the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have decided to make my own Tool bar

so i remove the regular Tool Bar :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar> //removetollbar
```

and make my own tool bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then i include in main xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/customtoolbar"
    android:id="@+id/custombar" >

</include>
```

and in the code i set it up :

```
_CustomToolBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) 
findViewById(R.id.custombar);
setSupportActionBar(_CustomToolBar);
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar _CustomToolBar;
```

> now when the app run the custom toolbar dont there

please help

Comment: Are you sure it's actually in the correct layout? Have you debugged to make sure `_CustomToolBar` is not null after the `findViewById()` line? Is there possibly some other `View` covering it in your main layout?

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience. To create a **CustomToolbar**, your step is corret. 
but I see there is a mistake in finding *View* for **CustomToolbar**.

I try to resolve your code.

1. Adding theme *NoActionBar* for remove default Toolbar. [Correct]
2. Create layout **CustomToolbar** like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"   // i adding id for custom toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

3. Include your **CustomToolbar** in Main xml. [Correct]
4. For setup your **CustomToolbar**, you must find view a toolbar(child view) in main(parent). based your case you include toolbar in Include view. So the code should be like:

```html
View parentView = (View) findViewById(R.id.custombar); // this ID layout include
Toolbar _CustomToolBar = (Toolbar) parentView.findViewById(R.id.custombar); // this ID CustomToolbar
setSupportActionBar(_CustomToolBar);
```

**UPDATE**

My answer was wrong, the problem is not on findViewById. After i see again, there is nothing wrong with your code. 
but my suggestion is try to create a different style for your **CustomToolbar**, so you can see the different. like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   // you can give background for example
   android:background="@android/color/black" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this helps...thanks you.